# ¿Por qué Visual Code ya no detecta el gcc de MinGW?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ide, compilador, mingw

Durante un par de años usé el MinGW "normalito" con VisualCode hasta que se volvió obsoleto.
Así que tuve migrar al nuevo MinGW pero ha sido un infierno por las diferentes opciones.
Según la documentación oficial de Visual Studio Code hay que usar el MinGW con MSYS2.
Hice la instalación correctamente, ya añadí el PATH en Variables de entorno y ya comprobé en CMD usando "gcc --version" que si lo detecte y si, todo funciona correctamente.
Tengo la extensión de C++ instalada.

Al seleccionarlo con IntelliSense no me da problema.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando quiero compilar, ya no me sale nada.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto pasó después de borrar la carpeta .vscode dentro de la carpeta del proyecto porque al querer compilar me salía el error:
"The preLaunchTask 'C/C++: g++.exe build active file' terminated with exit code 1"

Ya no sé que hacer, puros errores y problemas